# Is it easier to learn Chinese or Spanish?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters, learning

I'm a native English speaker as well as a native Spanish speaker. I speak Spanish to my family members most of the time at home. It didn't really take me too much effort to learn it. So I believe having a environment where the target language is spoken is very crucial.

My question is, after making my mind to seriously learn Chinese, the so-called language for the next decades, Is it easier to learn Chinese or to learn Spanish? (I know many people have said Chinese is difficult to learn, but after self-learning it for a few weeks so far, I found it is not as hard as I expected and actually it is interesting to learn though)

Comment: Please consider rephrasing this question so that it fits the site guidelines (available on the upper right-hand side whenever you ask a questions)>> Is your question about Chinese language? **We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.** Provide details. Share your research...

Comment: I think this question should be closed because it's too broad.

Comment: There are places where difficulty of learning various languages are compared and ranked so it can be objectively answered.

Comment: Chinese grammar is very easy for English speakers, but there is a very significant hurdle in learning both to produce and distinguish the sounds and tones. After three months recently trying to learn by immersion in China in Taiwan I didn't get over that hurdle. Years ago I learned Spanish by immersion in Mexico. Learning things such as gender, different word order, and irregular verbs in Spanish was much easier and often not essential for being able to communicate compared to learning the sounds of Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about comparing languages. It can be answered objectively on linguistics.SE though.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese is actually not hard to learn. People "think" it is hard because they only know 'European language system', they don't understand how those symbol works so they think it is hard to learn.

Which Chinese are you trying to learn? Cantonese? Mandarin? Mandarin is use all over China and Cantonese is use in Hong Kong and South East China. Mandarin is easier to learn, but Cantonese is the origin language in China.

Comment: "Cantonese is the origin language in China" oh really?

Comment: This claim is incorrect. While one may argue that Cantonese is closer to ancient spoken than Mandarin is, as far as we know, there was simply not one single "original (spoken) Chinese language" in the past. Historically, since there was credible history in China (i.e. during the Zhou dynasty), Chinese people in different regions had been speaking vastly different languages and these languages are not dialects of each other. Chinese languages actually became more and more convergent owing to population migrations. They did not diverge from a single "original language".